# change color to the same element angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class

Hi I have the following problem, when I click on an item changes color to all elements but I need to change only the color that I clicked:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as model">
   <button ng-click="model.addComparative()"> add
        </button>  
 <div ng-repeat="item in model.items track by $index">
   <button ng-model="model.myModel" ng-click="model.changeColor()" ng-class="{'red':model.myModel==true}">click me</button>
</div> 

 angular
    .module("myApp",[])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
        var model=this;
        model.myModel=false;
        model.items=[];
        model.newItems = '';
        model.addComparative = function(){
            model.items.push(model.newItems)
        }
        model.changeColor = function(){
            model.myModel = true;
        }
  })
```

and the codepen: http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/rrdZWE

Comment: because of your the model of the button. What actually you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the current index of each item:

**html file**

```
<button ng-model="model.myModel" ng-click="model.changeColor(item)" ng-class="{'red':item.selected==true}">click me</button>
```

**js file**

```
model.addComparative = function(){
    model.items.push({}); // What you append needs to be an object.
}
model.changeColor = function(item){
    item.selected = true;
};
```

Comment: if you are changing property of that item , simpler to pass whole item than index to function. Especially if any filters used because filters throw off indexing

Comment: I make another question, it is possible that the value of index Begin in a different number to zero?

Comment: Good @charlietfl I've edited according with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<button ng-model="model.myModel" 
        ng-click="this.item.red=true" 
        ng-class="{'red':this.item.red}">click me</button>
```

*ng-repeat*'s $index may vary between digest cycles (if items are not ordered), thus it is not reliable

adding set of 3 buttons on each "ADD" click and using JS *onclick*:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as model" ng-init="range=[0, 1, 2]">
  <button ng-click="model.addComparative()"> add </button>  
  <div ng-repeat="item in model.items track by $index+3">
    <button ng-repeat="i in range" 
            ng-model="model.myModel1" 
            onclick="this.style.background = 'red'">click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

also note that all your buttons have the same *ngModel*, probably it is not desired

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was testing your solution, but if they were more buttons, for each add, and I need to change color only the button that I clicked,
look: http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/rrdZWE